# Is there a way to leave notes in library code in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

due to reasons I am working with undocumented java library code that I cannot alter in any way or write into. Im using eclipse 2020-06 and I would like to leaves some notes for myself to make things easier. Is there a way to do that? or maybe an eclipse extension?

Answer (score 3):

You can use bookmarks. They work somewhat similarly to breakpoints, without pausing execution when you're debugging.

You can add them via the context menu.

[image: eclipse context menu showing add bookmark option]

If I recall, you're a bit limited by the amount of information you can add. It's basically just a single text box.

See the [help section on bookmarks](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-37-3c.htm)

Maybe there's some plugins which extend the functionality (e.g. [this one](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-bookmarks) for adding keyboard shortcuts)

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot set a bookmark in a dependency/library.